# Google Cloud Platform Datastore tutorial export command not recognized (Windows)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to go through the Datastore tutorial on https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/datastore-api-tutorial and I can't run the "export GCLOUD_PROJECT=" command in Windows (Step 6).  Any idea how to run a node export command in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a different tutorial.  Apparently you use "set" in place of "export" for Windows.

```
set GCLOUD_PROJECT=...
```

Also I found out that gcloud config has an option to set the current project as well which is what I used initially.